# Xcode Shows after deployment only white screen

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a problem with an existing app. Since ill updated some Pods (and Cocoapods) i am unable to bring my app to any device or simulator.

The simulator / device stays white, the memory usage increases every 1 second by approx. 20 Mbytes (so up to multiple Gigabytes) - but nothing happens. Stays white.

Ill already cleaned the app, removed all Pods and updated them again - but no success.

Any ideas?

The Debugger shows this:

[image]

And this (after 2 Minutes)

[image]

Edit: Ok now, pressed Debug - Pause, and shows this:

[image]

Edit again: It happens with a new Project too. Very strange. Ill try now to reinstall XCode.

Comment: Use the debugger and see what's happening.

Comment: I dont know whats happening, ill only see a spinner in debugger. Seems it run into serious memory problems, but i dont know why (app was running before without any problems)

Comment: Pause the app and look at the stack traces for each thread to see what's going on.

Comment: That might be a stupid question, but what do you mean with "pause the app" - i can only press on "Stop" - and then the app closes.  And i dont see any stack traces before, because the app seems its not running successfully. Or do you mean with instruments?

Comment: In the debugger, tap the "pause" icon.

Comment: Thanks rmaddy for your help, ill updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok found the solution. It was:

```
    let paddingView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 15, self.txtEmail.frame.height))
    txtEmail.leftView = paddingView
    txtEmail.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
    txtPassword.leftView = paddingView
    txtPassword.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
```

// brings app to crash, but no message, nothing. Takes up to 3 Gigabytes of Ram

```
    let paddingView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 15, self.txtEmail.frame.height))
    txtEmail.leftView = paddingView
    txtEmail.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always

    let paddingViewPassword = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 15, self.txtPassword.frame.height))
    txtPassword.leftView = paddingViewPassword
    txtPassword.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
```

Works fine...

Comment: I'm getting the exact same problem. Super high memory usage with a blank white screen. How did you go about finding out where the problem occurred?

Comment: Hi. Ill checked what i have changed since the problem occured, and it was this few lines of code. After removing it, everything was fine. Try to find out what you have changed